# What is the max number of contacts that can be injected in to Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Does anyone know what the maximum number of contacts that can be injected in one go? I know Journey builder is not meant to be a bulk deployment tool but I want to know if there is a limit on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'[Optimize Journey Builder Performance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_optimize_sending_in_journey_builder.htm&type=5)'

> When a journey has no entry filter, you can admit up to 2 million contacts per hour. When a journey has an entry filter, you can admit up to 250,000 contacts per hour. Following these general guidelines promotes efficient hourly processing.

Also review '[Journey Builder Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_builder_best_practices.htm&type=5)'